# В чем ошибка python многопоточность(виснет программа)?

Tags: python, многопоточность

Есть программа в ней 2 потока. Один поток выводит видео с камеры + распознование лиц, 2й выводит данные о памяти. При начале программы открывается окно и виснет. В чем заключается моя ошибка)? Иначе дико лагает
Вот мой код:

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime, time
import sys
import psutil


recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
id = 0
names = ['None', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
# запись
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3, 1920)
cam.set(4, 1080) # высота
minW = 0.1*cam.get(3)
minH = 0.1*cam.get(4)

def func1():
    ret, img =cam.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor = 1.2,
        minNeighbors = 5,
        minSize = (int(minW), int(minH)),
       )

    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
        id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])


        if (confidence < 100):

            id = names[id]
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))

        else:
            id = "unknown"
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))

        cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x+5,y-5), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x+5,y+h-5), font, 1, (255,255,0), 1)





def func2():
    mem_vert = psutil.virtual_memory()
    mem_vertt = round(mem_vert.used / 1073741824, 2)
    cv2.putText(img, str("RAM: ")+str(mem_vertt), (1100, 30), font, 0.9, (255,255,255), int(0.1))
    gpu_proz = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=True)
    gpu_prozz = round(gpu_proz, 1)
    cv2.putText(img,str("CPU: ")+str(gpu_prozz), (1100, 65), font, 0.9, (255,255,255), 1)


while True:
    ret, img =cam.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
    cv2.imshow('camera',img)
```

Comment: О, форк бомба) давно не встречал)

Answer (score 0):

То что у вас описанно в коде - это почти fork-bomb, но не совсем. На каждом шаге запускается по 2 потока, но не дожидаетесь их исполнения идете дальше. Данные изменяете не убедившись в безопасности операции.

Для начала в цикл после двух стартов добавь два .join() чтоб камера не шагала до окончания потоков

Дальше первая функция никуда не выводит свой результат.

А потом вторая функция не знает где взять img

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Буду исправлять.

Comment: Но у меня вопрос а как мне передать img из 1го потока во 2й. Что-то не пойму.